# Android - Recycler View with GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, android-recyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` that show results that come from `GCM` callbacks. The `RecyclerView` has a custom adapter a method add, there is also a progress bar that updates using an asynctask.

Message recieving over `GCM` that works fine:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.add(new ResultRecord("asf", 89, 1000));
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Add method in the custom adapter:

```
    public void add(final ResultRecord result) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                results.add(0, result);
                notifyItemInserted(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that the method add called and nothing happens on the UI. The method add called and then onBindViewHolder and the recycler view does not update. Only when the progress bar is finished the `RecylcerView` is getting update with all the `ViewHolder`s that has been added before.

I have checked if the add method works from the `onCreate` method and it worked fine. Maybe this problem is related to threading.

Comment: When a progressbar is present on the top,the activity is normal in the onPause state.Can that prevent the RV from updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Threading problem here.

Your code is based on ArrayList, which isn't Thread-Safe. You are calling the "Add" method from event, which called probably from multiple threads.

You have to synchronize your code. Something like this:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public void add(final ResultRecord result) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        AddNotThreadSafe(result); // Only one thread add in same time. Now is safe for executing. 
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Now, move your original `Add` code to separated method called `AddNotThreadSafe`.

This should work. :)